# TypeError: User.register is not a function at exports.register in passport-local-mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was trying to register a user using register function from [passport-local-mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose), but it was not working.

It is showing an error

> TypeError: User.register is not a function
> at exports.register (....\controllers\userController.js:62:10)

I have put all my controllers in controllers folder, routes ins routes folder and models in models folder.

**/modules/User.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const md5 = require('md5');
const validator = require('validator');
const mongodbErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-errors');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Address'],
        required: 'Please Supply an email address',
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please supply a name',
        trim: true,
    },
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });
userSchema.plugin(mongodbErrorHandler);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const storeController = require('../controllers/storeController');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers');

router.get('/', catchErrors(storeController.getStores));
router.get('/stores', catchErrors(storeController.getStores));
router.get('/add', storeController.addStore);

router.post(
    '/add',
    storeController.upload,
    catchErrors(storeController.resize),
    catchErrors(storeController.creatStore)
);

router.post(
    '/add/:id',
    storeController.upload,
    catchErrors(storeController.resize),
    catchErrors(storeController.updateStore)
);

router.get('/stores/:id/edit', catchErrors(storeController.editStore));
router.get('/store/:slug', catchErrors(storeController.getStoreBySlug));

router.get('/tags/:tag*?', catchErrors(storeController.getStoreByTag));

router.get('/login', userController.loginForm);
router.get('/register', userController.registerForm);

router.post('/register',
  userController.validateRegister,
  userController.register
);

module.exports = router;
```

**/controllers/userControllers.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('Store');

exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
};

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', { title: 'Register' });
};

exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
    req.sanitizeBody('name');
    req.checkBody('name', 'You must enter a name!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
    req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
        remove_dots: false,
        remove_extension: false,
        gmail_remove_subaddress: false,
    });
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody(
        'password-confirm',
        'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!'
    ).notEmpty();
    req.checkBody(
        'password-confirm',
        'Oops! Your password do not match'
    ).equals(req.body.password);

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        req.flash(
            'error',
            errors.map((err) => err.msg)
        );
        res.render('register', {
            tite: 'Register',
            body: req.body,
            flashes: req.flash(),
        });
        return;
    }
    next();
};

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name });
    User.register(user, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.send('there is some error check your console');
        }
        res.send('it works');
    });
};
```

I am not able to understand that why User.register is not a function.

I have read many articles and code related to this, in that it was working. But in my project it is not working. Is this because that my Schema, Routes and controllers are in different folder?

Comment: Maybe this `const User = mongoose.model('Store');` <-- **Store** should be **User** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /controllers/userControllers.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
```

I guess you tried to copy the layout from your other controller named `Store.js` and forget to rename the file name from which you are importing your modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

I think you did not provide a *schema name* i.e *userSchema* while making the User as a model.